# How to use Rank Function in MariaDb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying use the Rank function on MariaDB. I have already created some kind of RANK() implementation on my table but it's not working properly.

Two of the queries I have tried are these:

```
SELECT SpelarID, RondNr, Rondresultat, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY TavlingRondNr ORDER BY Rondresultat DESC)
FROM Resultatlista
WHERE RondNr = 1
ORDER BY Rondresultat DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

And

```
SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Rondresultat DESC)
FROM Resultatlista
WHERE TavlingRondNr = 1
ORDER BY Rondresultat DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

The result I get when i run it with phpMyAdmin is this:

MySQL said:

> Documentation
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '(PARTITION BY TavlingRondNr ORDER BY Rondresultat DESC) FROM
> Resultatlista WHE' at line 1

And for the second one I get a similar error message:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '(ORDER BY Rondresultat DESC) FROM Resultatlista WHERE
> TavlingRondNr = 1 ORDER' at line 1

Any suggestions to fix the SQL. I need to use it in an Update later.

Comment: What version of MariaDB are you using? `RANK()` was added in 10.2.

Comment: Running MariaDB on a Synology NAS. Upgraded to their latest supported version (Version: 5.5.53-0070) last week.

Answer (score 3):

Window functions were first introduced in **MariaDB 10.2**.0.

They do not exist in (and won't be added to) 5.5, 10.0, 10.1.

---

As of now, end of January 2017, the latest MariaDB 10.2.3 is a Beta release and is not recommended for production, but a release candidate is expected soon, and GA should not be far away, so it is worth trying.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm now asking Synology to upgrade their MariaDB package to at least version 10.2.0.

Comment: Don't use 10.2.0, use the latest 10.2.x that is available at the moment of upgrade. Currently it's 10.2.3; 10.2.4 is coming soon, and the next one after that might well be GA.

Answer (score -1):

RANK()

SELECT pid, name, age, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM players p, (
SELECT @curRank := 0
) q
ORDER BY age DESC, name

DENCE_RANK()

SELECT pid, name, age,
CASE
WHEN @prevRank = age THEN @curRank
WHEN @prevRank := age THEN @curRank := @curRank + 1
END AS rank
FROM players p,
(SELECT @curRank :=0, @prevRank := NULL) r
ORDER BY age

Its working